# How to export org mode to html using Google Fonts & CSS?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, css

I'm trying to change the headers and body fonts of HTML exported from org files. The idea is to have [Bebas Neue](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bebas+Neue?preview.text=TAAC&preview.text_type=custom&sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Bebas%20Neue#standard-styles) for headers and [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Lato:wght@300;400;700) for body (both are available through Google fonts).

first I associated my org file to a [customized CSS file I found](https://github.com/gongzhitaao/orgcss/blob/master/src/css/org.css):

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/style.css"/>
```

Then I added/replaced the following blocks to the CSS :

Google font import

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
```

Font variables setting

```css
@import "normalize";
@import "htmlize";
$bebas: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
$lato: 'Lato', sans-serif;
$monospace: Lucida Console, monospace;
$code-size: 80%;
$smaller: 90%;
$max-width: 710px;
```

Body

```css
body {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2% auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-family: $lato;
    color: #333;
}
```

Headers

```css
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color: #A5573E;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-family: $bebas;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Fonts don't change at all and I don't understand why..

Comment: I'm no expert on this,but those variables in css look sass-like preprocessor stuff, so ignored if you don't process it before. Check your browser console, or dev tools.

Comment: Indeed it works when I remove the variables. Thank you. Shall I remove the question?